# Add action button on the right side of navbar page

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `auth0` package for authentication in shiny. The package contains `auth0::logoutButton()`. I would like to put these button on the right side of the `NavbarPage` in Shiny app. Here is a simple app:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

ui <- navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Plot",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type",
                                           c("Scatter"="p", "Line"="l")
                              )
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("plot")
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Summary",
                          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                 )
                 ###

                 # HERE ADD loginButton() in new panel that will be on the right side for test any actionbutton

                 ###
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(cars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can try with `actionbutton` instead of `loginButton`. The solution will be the same.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure exactly what the HTML would be for `auth0:logoutButton()`, but you can add an action button to the upper right side of the `navbarPage` by adding an HTML script after your last `tabPanel` like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

ui <- navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Plot",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type",
                                           c("Scatter"="p", "Line"="l")
                              )
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("plot")
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Summary",
                          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                 ),
                 tags$script(
                   HTML("var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid');
                              header.append('<div style=\"float:right; padding-top: 8px\"><button id=\"signin\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary action-button\" onclick=\"signIn()\">Sign In</button></div>')")
                 )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(cars)
  })
}
```

Note: this code calls an undefined `signIn()` function, so you would want to alter the `onclick` behavior to match what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi.  this works well except it creates a hidden tabPanel and if youhover over it and click it produces another page with this:    var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid'); header.append('<div style="float:right; padding-top: 8px"><button id="signin" type="button" class="btn btn-primary action-button" onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button></div>').        var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid'); header.append('<div style="float:right; padding-top: 8px"><button id="signin" type="button" class="btn btn-primary action-button" onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button></div>').  Anyway to hide this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `auth0` but here's a generic solution. You can add a reactive expression to the server or an `onclick` argument to `actionButton`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    style = "padding: 0px;", # no gap in navbar
    actionButton("logout", "Log Out", icon = icon("user"),
                 style = "position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; z-index:10000;"),
    navbarPage(
        title = "My App",
        tabPanel("Panel 1", h1("Hi there"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$logout, {
        # do something
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer sticking with shiny functions `actionButton` or `actionLink`, you may find this helpful:

```
ui <- navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Plot",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type",
                                           c("Scatter"="p", "Line"="l")
                              )
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("plot")
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Summary",
                          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                 ),
                 actionLink("signing", "", icon = icon("sign-in-alt"),
                            style = "position: absolute; right: 20px; top: -3px")
)
```

Comment: Hi. This is not working for me. The action link does not appear