# Trigger evenReactive when navbarPage menu is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

I want to convert my NavbarPage tabPanel name (menu itme on top of page) into a Shiny widget, i.e. into an actionButton. If the user clicks on tabPanel 'Render_Text', then eventReactive should be triggered. Also the user navigates to the tabPanle page (as normally happens). Basically want 'Render_Text' to act like a button. Below code snippet does not work.

```
ui <- navbarPage("Hello World",
      tabPanel("About",
              textInput("Text1","Enter text:")
      ),
      tabPanel("Render_Text", value = "RS1",
              textOutput("Out_text1")
      )
)
server <- function(input,output,server){
          Out_text <- eventReactive(input$RS1,{input$Text1 })
                      output$Out_text1 <- renderText({Out_text()})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288216/add-action-button-on-the-right-side-of-navbar-page

Answer (score 0):

Basically, shiny always renders an output after a certain input was triggered (e.g. eventReactivce or observeEvent) or whenever needed. This means in your case that your textInput will always been shown when you click on the corresponding tabPanel:

```
ui <- navbarPage("Hello World",
                 tabPanel("About",textInput("Text1","Enter text:")
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Render_Text",textOutput("Out_text1")
                 )
)

server <- function(input,output,server){

    output$Out_text1 <- renderText({input$Text1})

    }
```

If I understand your requirements correctly, you do not need an actionButton at all. Let me know if I misunderstand you.

**UPDATE**

Maybe you mean something like that:

```
ui <- navbarPage("Hello World",id = "navbar",
                 tabPanel("About",value = "text",
                          textInput("Text1","Enter text:")
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Render_Text", value = "RS1",
                          textOutput("Out_text1")
                 )
)
server <- function(input,output,server){
    
    Out_text <- reactive({
        
        if (input$navbar == "RS1") {
            
            input$Text1
            
            }
        
        })
   
    output$Out_text1 <- renderText({
        
        Out_text()
        
        })

    }
```

Comment: That is correct. I do not want a button. The evenReactive should trigger only after "Render_Text" is clicked on the navbar. But sadly "Render_Text" is a tabPanel and it does not have an id. Hence I cannot trigger it like a actionButton. Basically "Render_Text" on Navbar should work like a button. Thanks!

Comment: But this is exactly what happens in my example above, isn't it? The textInput is rendered when you click on "Render_Text"...

Comment: The text entered in textInput should only appear after "Render_Text" is clicked. In reality I would like to run a simulation code to run after "Render_text" is clicked. We would usually use a button, but I dont want to use a button in this case.

Comment: The text entered in textInput DOES ONLY appear after "Render_Text" is clicked. Maybe you should adjust your MWE to give me a better idea of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As *thmschk* has said the rendering will be evoked when you click on the navbar anyway. However `navbarPage` does have an `id` associated with it and you can see what is clicked by listening to that:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Hello World",id = "RS1",
                 tabPanel("About",
                          textInput("Text1","Enter text:")
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Render_Text",
                          textOutput("Out_text1")
                 )
)

server <- function(input,output,server){

    Out_text <- eventReactive(input$RS1,{
        if(input$RS1 == "Render_Text"){
            input$Text1
        }else{
            return()
        }
    })
    
    output$Out_text1 <- renderText({
        Out_text()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: ooops, I didn't see your answer while I was updating my answer above. Sorry for that...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The statement is [ input$RS1 == "Render_Text" ] is the operative part of the solution. It worked for me.

Comment: In this case it would be nice if you accept the appropriate answer.