# a navbar button doesn't work on click in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

I wanted to place an email button on the navbar. I have looked around stackoverflow and on the web, however I couldn't find anything solid beside this- [Add action button on the right side of navbar page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288216/add-action-button-on-the-right-side-of-navbar-page). The closest I have gotten is by using the `fluidRrow` and column placements, but it looked cumbersome in my actual app.

At the moment, I have button placed where I wanted, however, it doesn't react. I know that I can use this within the `ui.R`-

```r
a(actionButton(inputId = "an_email", label = "Contact", 
                                icon = icon("envelope", lib = "font-awesome")),
                   href="mailto:xyz@email.us")
```

But not sure how to take this idea and go towards the `server.R` I would appreciate if somebody can help me.

```r
library(shiny)
# library(markdown)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Plot"
                 ),
                 tags$script(
                   HTML("var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid');
                              header.append('<div style=\"float:right; padding-top: 8px\"><button id=\"sendemail\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary action-button\" onclick=\"sendEmail()\">Contact</button></div>')")
                 )
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # not sure if I need an obserEvent here
  observeEvent(input$sendemail,{cat("contact envoked")})
  
  onclick("sendemail", runjs("window.open('mailto:xyz@email.us')"))
  
  # Tried this approach also
  #onclick("sendemail", runjs("function sendEmail() {
  #  var link = 'mailto:me@example.com';
  #  window.location.href = link;}"))
  #}


runApp(shinyApp(ui= ui, server= server))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I view your example in EDGE it is actually working (in Firefox the popup is blocked and in RStudio it is not working). However, you don't need the server part. You can just wrap the button in `<a href="mailto:xyz@email.us">...</a>`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Navbar!",
             tabPanel("Plot"),
             tags$script(
               HTML("var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid');
                              header.append('<div style=\"float:right; padding-top: 8px\"><a href=\"mailto:xyz@email.us\"><button id=\"sendemail\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary action-button\">Contact</button></a></div>')")
             )
  )), 
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  # no server part needed
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time buddy. Quick question if you don't mind, why is it not working on RStudio? Doesn't it creates a local server/browser upon Run, so it should open the default application email application, no? I am still new to Shiny, so apologies, not trying to sound smart.

Comment: I'm not sure what RStudio is using under the hood, but its good advise to preview dashboards in one of the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). RStudio is supporting more and more features, but at the end of the day it is not a full-fledged web browser.

Comment: Got it got it. Thank you again buddy for your answer. 1000X thanks! Take care.