# Action bottom on navbar panel in shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny, navbar, shinyapps

In my simple example I have a shiny app which I would like to add an action bottom to the navbar panel, the only way I could do was like put the action bottom as the `tabpanel` title :

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Navbar!",
  tabPanel("Plot"),
  tabPanel("summary"),
  navbarMenu(
    "More",
    tabPanel("Table"),
    tabPanel("About")
  ),
  tabPanel(actionButton("google_btn", "Open Google")),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$google_btn, {
    browseURL("https://www.google.com", encodeIfNeeded = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which is not really correct and in this way I can not move it to the far right of the page !
looking forward for a solution to add action bottom to the top right of navbar like screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288216/add-action-button-on-the-right-side-of-navbar-page)?